# Sql group by too many conditions

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Order    Product    Price  Quantity Description  
Order1   Product1   12      1       Text  
Order1   Product2   15      2       Text  
Order1   Product3   32      1       Text  
Order2   Product1   25      2       Text  
Order2   Product4   65      3       Text
```

And I need to show the details for Order 1 (product, price, qty, description), plus the total value of that order. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Order` is a SQL keyword, you'll need to quote it according to your database.

E.g., for SQL Server:

```
select m.*, ms.TotalValue
from MyTable m
inner join (
    select [Order], sum(Price * Quantity) as TotalValue
    from MyTable
    group by [Order]
) ms on m.[Order] = ms.[Order]
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2090a/2)

Comment: Updated with SQL Fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming total value = sum(price * quantity) then:

```
select t.[Order],
       t.Product,
       t.Price,
       t.Quantity,
       t.Description,
       aux.Total
from tablename t
inner join (
      select [Order],
             SUM(Price * Quantity) as 'Total'
      from tablename
      group by [Order]
) aux on t.[Order] = aux.[Order]
```

---

If you want the total for each line, you can do it like this:

```
select t.[Order],
       t.Product,
       t.Price,
       t.Quantity,
       t.Description,
       t.Price * t.Quantity as 'Total'
from tablename t
```